# How to get function address from loader DLL?

Tags: c++, winapi, dll

I have got 2 DLLs. DLL1 will be presented as MyDLL.dll and DLL2 is just a DLL containing extensions to MyDLL.
So to get these extensions from DLL2 to MyDLL, I need to load DLL2 inside MyDLL using LoadLibrary(). But here comes the problem. MyDLL contains one function, which will be very important in DLL2. And I need to reach that function. How do I do it?

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "DLL1API.h"

typedef DLL1API* (*PGetDLL1API)();

DLL1API *g_API;
void Init();
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hMod, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID reserve){
    switch(dwReason){
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        Init();
        break;
    }
}
void Init(){
    PGetDLL1API GetDLL1API;
    HMODULE mainDllMod=GetModuleHandleA("MyDLL.dll"); //how do I reach module of DLL1?
    GetDLL1API=(PGetDLL1API)GetProcAddress(mainDllMod,"GetDLL1API");
    if(GetDLL1API){
        g_API=GetDLL1API();
        printf("DLL1API: %p",g_API);
    } else { //always gets to this result :(
        printf("Error, failed to get GetDLL1API()!\n");
    }
}
```

Other thing is, that I am scared to use LoadLibrary("MyDLL.dll") inside DLL2, because I think it would cause one big infinite loadLibrary loop (MyDll => DLL2 => MyDLL ...)

Comment: Load DLL1 first, then load the DLL2; in DLL2 add a function `setupCore(void (*funtion_ptr)())` (or something similar), and pass the address of the needed function from DLL1 to that.

Answer (score 0):

Calling LoadLibrary from inside DllMain is [not recommended](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/27/63401.aspx).  Fix that, and your circular loading concerns will go away as well.

BTW DLL2 doesn't need to load DLL1.  It can use `GetModuleHandle` to find the already-loaded DLL to pass to `GetProcAddress`, use a static import, or DLL1 can call a function exported from DLL2 passing a function pointer.

- More suggested reading, with specific notes on `LoadLibrary`: http://blog.barthe.ph/2009/07/30/no-stdlib-in-dllmai/

Comment: IMO, DLL2 should call LoadLibrary to increment the loader reference count unless there's no chance of confusion in what function will be called at what point.

Answer (score 0):

You are right to not want to use `LoadLibrary` in DllMain.  Using `LoadLibrary` in DllMain is expressly forbidden according to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Microsoft page.  Also, [GetModuleHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683199%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) only works if the DLL has already been loaded by the current process.

Are you really sure you need to load the DLL from your DllMain?  You could just call `GetModuleHandle` from your exported functions, assuming of course that the module has been loaded by the program already.